# CSS/jQuery not showing in Drupal 7 when upgraded from 6

Tags: javascript, theming, upgrading

I have just recently upgraded a large site from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7. When I load up the site it doesn't load any theme at all. Even when I check the admin panel under appearance it  shows the enabled themes, but nothing shows up at all, style wise. When I view the source, it isn't pulling in any CSS or jQuery files at all. Does anyone know how I would go about fixing this?

Also, I am receiving this error '***The specified file temporary://fileoR4rjt could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.***'

I thought it may have something to do with the tmp folder/file-system but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Any help would be great. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Theming system as a little bit changed on Drupal 7. You should give a look at [that page](http://drupal.org/node/254940) for more informations.

For your file-system problem, you should check the configuration of File system and see where is trying to put the files from the temporary folder.

By default Drupal tries to put that into sites/default/files, so check if the rights of this folder as write/execute/read for the owner and the groupe and if the group is at least the web server.

Also, maybe this problem with file-system can likely fixe your CSS/jQuery problem. So try to fix it before read the documentation from the new theming changes on Drupal 7.